# How can I rename a sequence with liquibase?

Tags: liquibase

I have a sequence in my database, which I generated through Liquibase. During refactoring, we decided that we didn't like the name that we gave it, and we would like to rename it, preserving all data that currently exists for it.

It seems possible to [alter a sequence](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/alter_sequence.html), but I'm not seeing anything about how to rename the sequence. Is there a way to do it, or a reasonable workaround?

(If it matters, I'm using Oracle SQL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not currently a built-in refactoring to rename a sequence. If your database engine supports it, you could execute whatever methods are supported using a `<sql>` or `<sqlFile>` change.

You said you were using Oracle SQL. The [RENAME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9019.htm) statement allows for renaming a sequence. So your Liquibase script would look like this:

```
<sql>RENAME old_sequence_name TO new_sequence_name</sql>
```

Comment: Apparelntly, that's no longer the case. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39378483/875485).

Answer (score 7):

Although not documented, this refactoring is supported by Liquibase. Not sure what version this change was implemented in, but the [class supporting the feature](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/e0badd697d82a87ba868b41e68b659cf8c8e68e8/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/change/core/RenameSequenceChange.java) was commited on 30 Jan 2014. What's interesting though, is that the [original issue](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1598) is still unresolved.

Anyway, the refactoring is supposed to be working only on **Oracle** and **Postgres**. I've tested it on **Oracle** with **Liquibase 3.4.1**:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: change_set_id
      author: me
      dbms: oracle
      changes:
        - renameSequence:
            oldSequenceName: old_name_seq
            newSequenceName: new_name_seq
```

The above refactoring is in YAML format, but you could easily guess its XML counterpart.

On Oracle, this generates the following statement:

```
RENAME old_name_seq TO new_name_seq;
```

2 other supported parameters are `catalogName` and `schemaName`.

Comment: I just tried this with Liquibase 3.5.3 on Postgres using XML format and it did not work. It may be that the XML file is being validated against its schema, which does not include this as a vaild element.

Comment: @TimDean well, maybe that explains why the feature is not officially documented. It worked for me with Oracle/YAML.

Comment: I had to use http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd to be able to use renameSequence with XML changelog